# Doctrine2 One to One Relation and extra table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have 3 tables:
users, users_profile and extra table users_addresses.

User class:

```
class User
{

        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @var int
         */
        private $userId;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\UserProfile", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="user", fetch="LAZY")
         * @var Entity\UserProfile
         */
        private $profile;

        /**
         * @param Entity\UserProfile $profile
         */
        public function setProfile(UserProfile $profile) {
            $this->profile = $profile;
            $profile->setUser($this);

            return $this;
        }
        (...)
}
```

User profile class

```
class UserProfile
{ 
        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\Column(name="profile_id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @var int
         */
        private $profileId;


        /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\User", inversedBy="profile")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
         * @var Entity\User
         */
        private $user;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Address", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_addresses",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="address_id")}
         *      )
         **/
        private $addresses;

        /**
         * @param Address $address
         */
        public function addAddress(Address $address) {
            if (!$this->addresses->contains($address)) {
                $this->addresses->add($address);
            }

            return $this;
        }

        (...)
}
```

Address class

```
class Address
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="address_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @var int
     */
    private $addressId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    private $city;

    (...)
}
```

Add user with profile data and address

```
$userAddress = new \Entity\Address();
$userAddress->setStreet($street);
$userAddress->setCity($city);
$userAddress->setCountry($country);
$userAddress->setState($state);
$userAddress->setZipCode($zipCode);

$userProfile = new \Entity\UserProfile();
$userProfile->addAddress($userAddress);

$user = new \Entity\User();
$user->setProfile($userProfile);

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

The problem i am having at the moment is that the entities persist ok, but the 'user_id' in the join table ('users_addresses') is not correct ('user_id' = 0, 'address_id' = correct). Table 'addresses' must not contain extra field like 'user_id'. What am I doing wrong?

I need a structure like this:
[image: structure]

Comment: Please clarify the sentence : "When I add a user in an additional table saves address_id and profile_id instead user_id." Could you please describe by an example?

Comment: You need an `Address` class as well, don't you? Could you provide the actual script you are using to do the user creation?

Comment: Why did you make a User Address many-to-many relationship, when it's actually a UserProfile to Address relationship AND you only have 2 addresses per profile (so you don't need a many-to-many, but just 2 one-to -one)?

Comment: 'Address' is a table of global addresses

Comment: I think the problem comes frome this line in profileClass  `joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id"....`

Answer (score 0):

Your modeling shows that tables `users` and `users_profile` share the same primary key, namely `user_id`, and thus that column is also a foreign key toward `users` in `users_profile`.

Hence, you should replace `profile_id` in the Php annotations by `user_id`, remove the key auto generation directive, and update (or delete and recreate) the schema.

```
class UserProfile {
    /**
      * @ORM\Id
      *     @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
      * @var int
      */
     private $profileId;

     /* ... */
}
```

Then

```
$ doctrine orm:info --verbose
Found 3 mapped entities:
[OK]     Address
[OK]     User
[OK]     UserProfile
$ doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
ATTENTION: This operation should not be executed in a production environmnent.

Creating database schema...
Database schema created successfully!
```

Or use the `update` command if you already have a schema.

You could also rename the php class attribute (`$profileId`), for "consistency" with the DB model, but I don't think it matters much, unless you have code which relies on a specific name.